# What are gross concessions on filling 424(b)(2)?

Tags: bonds

In [this](https://quotes.quotemedia.com/data/downloadFiling?webmasterId=104600&ref=317702144&type=HTML&formType=424B2&formDescription=Prospectus%20%5BRule%20424%28b%29%282%29%5D&dateFiled=2023-08-21&cik=0000732712) filling, for the bond with CUSIP 92346MLS8, the "Gross concession" is 3.150%.

Is this the total fee paid to issue the bond?

Why is it so high for a bond with a fixed 5.3% coupon?